# How to get the number of days between two java dates, comparing both the date and also time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two java `date` objects using the following code:

```
public static int daysBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate)
    {
        return Days.daysBetween( new LocalDate(startDate.getTime()), new LocalDate(endDate.getTime())).getDays(); 
    }
```

I am using the `Joda` time here. But my problem is that when I compare two dates, example : Mon Apr 11 09:04:00 IST 2016 and Wed Apr 13 11:04:00 IST 2016, the result I get is 2. In fact the result I am expecting is 3 since there is more than 2 days between the given dates. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Are you saying you want the result to be rounded up, rather than down?

Comment: @David Wallace, exactly

Comment: You could just add one to the result if the end time isn't the same as the start time.

Comment: Note that you should not use `LocalDate` if you're interested in sub-date timespans - `LocalDate` drops the time component of your start and end dates leaving you with an exact number of days. `LocalDateTime` includes times but drops time zones, while `DateTime` also ensures the time zone is persisted. In this case I would probably use `DateTime`.

Comment: Good point, @dimo414 - and why I'm using `LocalDateTime` in the example in my answer instead of `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](https://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween(org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,org.joda.time.ReadablePartial)) for `Days.daysBetween()` says (emphasis mine):

> Creates a Days representing the **number of whole days** between the two
> specified partial datetimes.

So just check whether there are any "left-overs", and increase if that's the case:

```
LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime then = now.minusDays(2).minusMinutes(5);
int numberOfDaysBetween = Days.daysBetween(then, now).getDays();
LocalDateTime fullDayTime = then.plusDays(numberOfDaysBetween);
if (fullDayTime.isBefore(now)) {
    numberOfDaysBetween++;
}
```

This should end up with `numberOfDaysBetween` being 3, since `then` is 2 days *and 5 minutes* before `now`.

Answer (score 0):

No absolute need to use Joda time, or java.time, here.  A day is (86400 * 1000) milliseconds.  Java `Date`s give you the current time as UTC milliseconds in the Posix epoch. So ...

```
long diffMillis = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
int deltaDays = (int) Math.ceil(diffMillis / (86400.0 * 1000.0));
```

Comment: But a day is NOT necessarily 86400000 milliseconds.  When daylight savings starts, we get a 23-hour day; and when daylight savings ends, we get a 25-hour day.  The Joda and java.time libraries take account of that in their calculations.  If you don't use one of them, you'll more-than-likely get this badly wrong.

Comment: It depends on how you define a day.  In local time, when time zone offsets are applied, the period between midnight to midnight may contain 23, 24, or 25 hours depending on whether a transition occurs.  However, in UTC no time zone offsets ever apply and so a day is always 86400 seconds.